# Moment Convert From/To ISOString with Timezone

Tags: coffeescript, momentjs

```
moment = require('moment-timezone')

fromISO = (format, dateISO)->
  if !format? then format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
  return moment(dateISO).tz("Europe/Amsterdam").format(format)

toISO = (dateTime)->
   return moment(dateTime, "DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm:ss").tz("Europe/Amsterdam").toISOString()
```

## Question

First I want to convert from an ISOString to a specific format in a specific timezone.

Second the other way around.

Unfortunately, it ignores the timezone. I always get the same ISOString back. In the browser console, it takes my local time of the browser, on my server it just converts it without subtracting time.

PS: First I used:

```
return moment(dateISO).utcOffset('+02:00').format(format)

return moment(dateTime, "DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm:ss").utcOffset('-02:00').toISOString()
```

Currently, I use `.add` and `.subtract`

Comment: Which is your issue? Which language are you using in your code sample? I didn't understand what you are trying to do, anyway note that [`toISOString()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/): _always returns a timestamp in UTC, even if the moment in question is in local mode._

Comment: Thx, I think I got it. My problem was that I had string with a local time, e.g. `"2014-06-01 12:00"` in `Europe/Amsterdam` but no matter which time zone I specified in the code, it always returned the same ISO time. It just took the time zone of the server or browser.

Answer (score 1):

This works in Chrome:

**From a local time to ISO:**

```
moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "Europe/Amsterdam").toISOString()
```

instead of

```
moment("2014-06-01 12:00").tz("Europe/Amsterdam").toISOString()
```

**From ISO time to local**

```
moment.tz(dateISO,"Europe/Amsterdam").format(format)
```